# date totimestring replace hh:MM

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var myDate = new Date(r.date).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
```

which returns the format in hh:MM:ss

However I only want the hh:MM formatwithout the seconds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the last part of the regexp (the one that includes the seconds) out of the group, like this

```
var myDate = new Date(r.date).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}.*/, "$1");
```

so that the substitution only takes the first two numbers, a colon and another couple of numbers into account.